# Select only one row from a group in a data.table

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I am  having a data table which contains multiple rows with same group like below.

```
a=data.table(q=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),r=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),s=c(1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1),t=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

From this I want only one unique row from the group q,r,s.
I tried

```
unique(a)
   q r s t
1: 1 1 1 1
2: 1 1 3 2
3: 1 1 1 3
4: 2 1 3 1
5: 2 1 1 2
6: 2 1 3 3
7: 3 1 1 1
8: 3 1 3 2
9: 3 1 1 3
```

which returns the unique rows over all but not one from the group.

```
 a[!duplicated(a$q,a$r,a$s)]
   q r s t
1: 1 1 1 1
2: 1 1 3 2
3: 1 1 1 3
4: 2 1 3 3
5: 3 1 1 3
```

when I try this one I loose the row

```
   3 1 3 2
```

My  desired output is something like

```
   q r s t
1: 1 1 1 1
2: 1 1 3 2
3: 2 1 3 1
4: 2 1 1 2
5: 3 1 1 1
6: 3 1 3 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: unique(a, by = c('q','r','s'))

Answer (score 2):

From the document : *a vector or a data frame or an array or NULL* (Not multiple arrays)

```
a[!(duplicated(a[,c('q','r','s')]))]
   q r s t
1: 1 1 1 1
2: 1 1 3 2
3: 2 1 3 1
4: 2 1 1 2
5: 3 1 1 1
6: 3 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can do this:

```
require(dplyr)

distinct(a, q, r, s, .keep_all = TRUE)

#    q r s t
# 1: 1 1 1 1
# 2: 1 1 3 2
# 3: 2 1 3 1
# 4: 2 1 1 2
# 5: 3 1 1 1
# 6: 3 1 3 2
```